# How can I pass a variable and a string into the same jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following:

> ```
> var x = '.'+this.id;
> ```

and this does not work:

> ```
> $(x,'#thumb').show();
> ```

but this does:

> ```
> $(x).show();
> ```

and obviously so does this:

> ```
> $('#thumb').show();
> ```

What am I missing? Should I be doing something else in general to pass variables (even on their own) through jQuery?

Comment: string concatenation?  _myVar + "my string"_

Comment: Well, $(x + '#thumbs').show() 
doesn't work. 
$(x+', #thumbs').show()  
works fine. But it looks so sloppy.

Comment: Too bad jquery can't read minds, why didn't creators think of that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate the two strings together:

```
$(x+',#thumb').show();
```